# Custom Segue - prevent flickering on removeFromSuperview

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the following code to perform a custom segue:

```
class PopFromMiddleSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
override func perform()
{
    let sourceVC = self.sourceViewController
    let destinationVC = self.destinationViewController

    sourceVC.view.addSubview(destinationVC.view)
    destinationVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.05, 0.05)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in

        destinationVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
        }) { (finished) -> Void in

            destinationVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
            let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.001 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
            dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                sourceVC.presentViewController(destinationVC, animated: false, completion: nil)

            }
    }
}
```

}

At the end of the animation `destinationVC` flickers for a second. You can shortly see `sourceVC`, then the animation is done.

I'm able to remove that, if I put `//destinationVC.view.removeFromSuperview()`

But the next time I go back to that view by segue, my app crashes.

How can I remove that flicker? Any help is very appreciated.